# Convert/fold multiple return values into a struct in Go

Tags: go

Consider the following example:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func abc() (string, error) {
    return "x", nil
}

type Result struct {
    str string
    err error
}

func xyz(res Result) {
    fmt.Println(res)
}

func main() {
    str, err := abc()
    s := Result{str: str, err: err}
    xyz(s)
}
```

What I want is to avoid having to use temporaries

```golang
    str, err := abc()
    s := Result{str: str, err: err}
```

And directly create a struct `s` from the return values of `abc()`. Something like this:

```golang
    s := Result{abc()} // Does not work: multiple-value abc() in single-value context
```

In other words, **is there a shortcut in Go for converting/folding multiple return values into a struct?**

Note: I cannot change the signatures of functions `abc()` and `xyz()` (library functions).

Comment: Multiple assignment works just fine with struct fields, but you have to specify them: https://play.golang.org/p/CpSoVYxh9f7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [I]s there a shortcut in Go for converting/folding multiple return values into a struct?

No.

Answer (score 3):

Answer mentioned by @Peter but not provided here.

```
var s Result
s.str, s.err = abc()
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to avoid having to use temporaries
>
> And directly create a struct s from the return values of abc()

I guess that depends on your definition of "directly."

```
func MakeResult(str string, err error) Result {
  return Result{str, err}
}

s := MakeResult(abc())
```